# Did Max Rebo die on the sail barge?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

The musician Max Rebo and his band played for Jabba in his palace, and at least Max Rebo was performing on the Sail Barge when Jabba set out for the Great Pit of Carkoon.

So knowing that, was Max Rebo killed when the barge blew up or did he somehow escape when things hit the fan?

Comment: I thought I'd see this pop up after The Book of Boba Fett 1x1...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Star Wars Insider #67](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_67), the band managed to leap to safety before the barge exploded. The same article notes that Rebo became wealthy and ultimately retired to Coruscant.

[image]

> The Max Rebo Twelve, as they now were called, were ordered to perform during the execution of Leia Organa, Luke Skywalker, and Chewbacca the Wookiee. As Jabba’s sail barge went down in a fiery explosion, the band barely jumped to safety. They would surely have died if not for Greeata and Lyn Me. The two drove off a band of Tusken Raiders and took their banthas.
>
> Released from their contract to Jabba, the musicians went their separate ways. Snootles and Rebo took a gig at Lady Valorian’s as the Max Rebo Duo, reverting back to the Max Rebo Band when Rystáll and Greeata re-joined. Rebo was ecstatic at seeing his old partners again, but Snootles eventually went solo, even turning her back on her long-time friend Greeata.

This incident can be seen in the Legends short story; [And the Band Played On: The Band's Tale](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/And_the_Band_Played_On:_The_Band%27s_Tale)

> Droopy jumped without a second’s hesitation.
>
> “Come on, Max,” Sy said. “It’s not that far, and you can slide down
> the steering vane most of the way.
>
> There’s sand below. It’ll help break your fall.”
>
> Turning, she jumped.
>
> Max pushed open the shutter and looked down. It seemed like an awfully
> long way. He hesitated. Droopy helped Sy up. They both looked unhurt.
>
> “Jump!” Sy Snoodles called. “Max—jump!”
>
> Something exploded behind Max, and the force of the blast was like a
> shove in Max’s back. He flew out the viewport, over Sy and Droopy, and
> hit the sand flat on his back.
>
> The fall stunned him. His’ hands and face stung, and a ringing sound
> filled his ears. He was distantly aware of someone picking him up and
> carrying him away from the sail barge, which seemed to be.burning.
>
> He raised his head just in time to see the barge explode in a huge
> orange fireball.

Comment: Worth noting: these are legends sources.

Comment: Which I noted in my answer

Answer (score 7):

### Max Rebo Lives!

As per episode one of the 2021 Disney+ TV series *Book of Boba Fett* (titled: “Stranger in a Strange Land”) Max Rebo is alive and well and “[Jizz-waling](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jizz-wailer)” on his organ with some random [Bith](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bith/Legends) at the [Mos Espa](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mos_Espa) cantina on Tatooine circa 9 [ABY](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/%27ABY-BBY%27_dating_system):

[image: Max Rebo being the best Max Rebo he can be.]

Comment: can't believe they put the name of that musical style in anything, let alone a junior novelization lol

Comment: We're sure this is Rebo, and not just another musician from the same species?